# How to retry for fixed amount of time after all previous retries are exhausted in Kafka consumer?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-retry, exponential-backoff

I am using exponential retry in Kafka consumer. And it is working as expected but I need to add some more configuration to it. Suppose after the maximum retry attempt, the request is still not successful then I need to retry it for a fixed time thereafter. 
Suppose the multiplier is 2 and the maximum retry attempt is 4 with an initial retry interval 1sec
Then retry sequence will be 
**1sec, 2 sec, 4 sec, 8 sec.**

After the fourth attempt, I need retry to occur at a fixed interval (say after each 10sec) until the request is successful.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `ExponentialBackOffPolicy` in the `RetryTemplate`, you can set its `maxInterval` property.

If you are using a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with an `ExponentialBackOff` instead (which is preferred with modern versions of spring-kafka - to avoid a rebalance), it, too, has a `maxInterval` property.